# Sorting a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function that takes a list of sorted lists, then merges everything together and sorts them again.

I managed to write this so far:

```
merge_:: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a] --takes in the list and merges it
merge_ [] = []
merge_ (x:xs) = x ++ merge_ xs

isort:: Ord a => [a] -> [a] --Sorts a list
isort [] = []
isort (a:x) = ins a (isort x)
        where
            ins a []                = [a]
            ins a (b:y) | a<= b     = a:(b:y)
                        | otherwise = b: (ins a y)
```

I haven't been able to find a way to combine these two in one function in a way that makes sense. Note that I'm not allowed to use things such as ('.', '$'..etc) (homework)

Comment: Do you have to write a function that takes a list of lists? Usually, you would write `merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem  I'm having. I can't think of a way to make it work for a list of lists.

Comment: Do you know `foldr` or `foldl`? Homework questions are always tricky to answer, since you don't necessarily know what the pupil must not use.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the highest we've reached is high order functions and search/sort algorithms.

Comment: A fold is a higher-order function. :) But I guess these means that folds are off-limits for the purpose of your homework.

Comment: `doBoth :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]; doBoth xss = isort (merge_ xss)`?

Comment: Man, I feel a little dumb right now. Yes, that was actually all I needed to do (with my pre-existing code). Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, this whole problem done properly is `sort . concat`.  I swear one day I'm going to start a hall of shame website for teachers who foist this hobbled, bastardized form of functional programming on students instead of making the problems a little more interesting.

Comment: I don't know, we are often asked to redefine functions from the prelude, perhaps to understand how they work? I'm not really in a position to judge because I'm just a beginner, but it does get tedious at times.

Answer (score 5):

We start simple. How do we merge *two* sorted lists?

```
mergeTwo :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeTwo [] ys         = ys
mergeTwo xs []         = xs
mergeTwo (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x <= y    = x : mergeTwo    xs  (y:ys)
  | otherwise = y : mergeTwo (x:xs)    ys
```

How do we merge multiple? Well, we start with the first and the second and merge them together. Then we merge the new one and the third together:

```
mergeAll :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
mergeAll (x:y:xs) = mergeAll ((mergeTwo x y) : xs)
mergeAll [x]      = x
mergeAll _        = []
```

Allright. Now, to sort all elements, we need to create a list from every element, and then merge them back. Let's write a function that creates a list for a single item:

```
toList :: a -> [a]
toList x = -- exercise
```

And now a function to wrap all elements in lists:

```
allToList :: [a] -> [[a]]
allToList = -- exercise
```

And now we're done. We simply need to use `allToList` and then `mergeAll`:

```
isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
isort xs = mergeAll (allToList xs)
```

Note that this exercise got a lot easier since we've split it into four functions.

#### Exercises (which might not be possible for you(r homework))

- Write `toList` and `allToList`.
- Try a list comprehension for `allToList`. Try a higher order function for `allToList`.
- Write `isort` point-free (with `(.)`).
- Check whether there is already a `toList` function with the same type. Use that one.
- Rewrite `mergeAll` using `foldr`

Comment: Question: what difference does it make whether the given list is pre-sorted or not? Aren't they gonna get re-sorted anyway?

Comment: @Rad huh? The lists for `mergeTwo` have to be sorted, if that's what you're asking about. After all, a proper merge will only look at the "start" of the (unprocessed) list/array. The list for `isort` does not (obviously).

Comment: Okay, I get it. I'll start working on those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] l1 = l1
merge l1 [] = l1
merge (e1:l1) (e2:l2)
    | e1<e2 = e1:merge l1 (e2:l2)
    | otherwise = e2:merge (e1:l1) l2
```

Comment: That doesn't have the same type as OP's `merge`.

Comment: You're right, this takes two lists, and merges into one.